# How to git ignore subfolders but not the files in first level

Tags: git

I have this folder structure and I need to ignore everything except the files (.R) in the scenario1,2 folders

```
--workspace
      |--scenario1
           |--data (folder)
           |--outputs (folder)
           |--xx1.R
           |--xx2.R
      |--scenario2
           |--data (folder)
           |--outputs (folder)
           |--xx1.R
           |--xx2.R
```

I have `scenario1/*/` which seems not to work

Comment: What you have should successfully and summarily ignore all directories in `scenario1`. If you've got a similar line for `scenario2` this should do what you want on that structure. Show the evidence you're looking at. What specifically are you trying, what are you seeing, what did you expect?

Comment: The usual reason for a `.gitignore` to seemingly have no effect at all is encoding trouble. Make sure it's saved as utf8 or ascii.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the scenario folders are in the root of your project, `scenario1/*/` isn't what you're after. That will ignore everything inside scenario1. It sounds to me that you want to ignore the `data` and `outputs` folders, but include the `.R` files. There are two solutions I'm providing below:

- To ignore all subdirectories and files within the scenario folders but include the .R files (see the note below for caveats).

  - Add `scenario*/*`
  - Add `!*.R`

**NOTE:** The `!` will re-include files/folders that were previously ignored by a matching pattern. However, the parent folder the R files are in must not be ignored. If you make a subdirectory that includes R files within the scenario folders, you'll have to use `-f` with `git add` to forcibly add them.

- Ignoring any folders matching `outputs` or `data` but allow all other files/folders within scenario1 and scenario2

  - Add `**/data/`
  - Add `**/outputs/`

I'd go with the second option since it's less of an inconvenience for you and other contributors, assuming it still meets your requirements.

Comment: I agree with the second option. It is more explicit and less likely to cause problems than the first option.

Comment: Still not working. Just to clarify: Should I have only one `.gitignore` file or have multiple in each of the `scenario` files?

Comment: @jmulua You can have multiple `.gitignore` files, but it's not required. It might be useful, say, if you have highly specialized subfolders (like in the Linux kernel) or are managing multiple projects in one repo, etc. Are you having issues with the first approach I listed or the second one?